# "must match numbers of columns" error in dynlm in R

Tags: r

I have the folllowing codes:

```
y<-my.data$GDP
tt<-my.data$period
dataset<-data.frame(y,tt)
gnp.lm <- dynlm(formula = y ~ L(d(y), 1:10) + 1 + L(y) + tt, data = dataset)
```

Both `my.data$period` and `my.data$GDP` are one-dimensional arrays with the same lengths.

However, I got the following error message:

```
error in fix.by(by.x x) 'by' must match numbers of columns.
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: hard to do anything without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Just cosmetic, but you should be able to use `dynlm(GDP ~ L(d(GDP), 1:10) + 1 + L(GDP) + period, data = my.data)` (i.e. no need to create a new data frame)

Comment: Two comments from trying to reproduce: (1) I think if you want 10 separate lags you need to specify them separately (i.e. `L(.,1)`+L(.,2)+L(.,3)+...`) -- even though the documentation claims you can use a vector-valued lag; (2) I'm not sure you can use `L(d(y))`; I get an error when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving a reproducible example, the following reason could be the answer:

```
obs <- 1000
y <- rnorm(1000)
tt <- 1:obs

dataset <- data.frame(y, tt)
dyn_lm <- dynlm(y~L(y,1:5)+ tt)
```

Here, the error occurs due to the problem of the unknown class of y. But if you specifiy the class of y and tt to be of ts, it perfectly works.

```
y.ts <- ts(y)
tt.ts<-ts(tt)

dyn_lm_ts <- dynlm(y.ts~L(y.ts,1:5)+ tt.ts)
```